# Hyperledger composer consuming external data

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-composer

I would like to know if it is possible in *hyperledger-composer* to consume data from an existing database. For example, can I create assets and participants based on external data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your scenario, you could use 'push' data into Composer using the [Composer REST API server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/integrating-index) endpoints.

You could also 'pull' data into Composer by using the Request module [described here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out).

You could also write a NodeRED flow with Composer Nodes to move data into Composer (and Hyperledger Fabric).